# I want to plot the solution but

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

I want to plot this solution for the different value of d and x but it is an Elliptic function.

```
   Clear["Global`*"]
   eqns2 = {g'[x]^2 == (f*g[x]^2) - k + d/g[x]};
   f = 0.69; k = -0.001;
   sol2 = DSolve[eqns2, g[x], x]
```

I don't know how to plot this!!

Answer (score 6):

To plot solutions for $y'=f(x,y)$ without solving it and without having initial conditions, the command is

```
StreamPlot[{1, f[x,y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

This will plot all families of solutions. An initial condition will pick one of these.

For your ode, there are two set of solution families, due to the square root. Therefore you can do

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns2 = {y'[x]^2 == (f*y[x]^2) - k + d/y[x]};
f = 69/100; k = -1/1000;
Manipulate[
 f1 = Sqrt[(f*y^2) - k + d/y] /. d -> d0;
 Grid[{{Row[{"d=", d0}], SpanFromLeft},
   {Row[{"Showing both solutions"}], SpanFromLeft},
   {StreamPlot[{1, f1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2.6}], 
    StreamPlot[{1, -f1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 2.6}]}}]
 ,
 {{d0, 1, "d?"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0}
 ]
```

[image]

To better see the above matches the solutions given by `NDSolve`, lets add initial conditions $y(0)=1$

[image]

**code**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns2 = {y'[x]^2 == (f*y[x]^2) - k + d/y[x]};
f = 69/100; k = -1/1000;
Manipulate[
 f1 = Sqrt[(f*y^2) - k + d/y] /. d -> d0;
 Grid[{{Row[{"d=", d0}], SpanFromLeft},
   {Row[{"Showing both solutions"}], SpanFromLeft},
   {StreamPlot[{1, f1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2.6},
     StreamPoints -> {{{0, 1}, Red}}, ImageSize -> 300],
    StreamPlot[{1, -f1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2.6},
     StreamPoints -> {{{0, 1}, Red}}, ImageSize -> 300]
    }
   }]
 ,
 {{d0, 1, "d?"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0}
 ]
```

Or you can combine them into one plot

[image]

**code**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns2 = {y'[x]^2 == (f*y[x]^2) - k + d/y[x]};
f = 69/100; k = -1/1000;
Manipulate[
 f1 = Sqrt[(f*y^2) - k + d/y] /. d -> d0;
 Grid[{{Row[{"d=", d0}], SpanFromLeft},
   {Row[{"Showing both solutions"}], SpanFromLeft},
   {Show[StreamPlot[{1, f1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2.6},
      StreamPoints -> {{{0, 1}, Red}}, ImageSize -> 300],
     StreamPlot[{1, -f1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2.6},
      StreamPoints -> {{{0, 1}, Red}}, ImageSize -> 300]]
    }
   }]
 ,
 {{d0, 1, "d?"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0}
 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

- The equation have complex solution. We need to use `ReImPlot`.

```
f = 0.69; k = -0.001;
eqns2 = {g'[x]^2 == (f*g[x]^2) - k + d/g[x]};
g0 = 1;
d = 2;
sol = NDSolve[{eqns2, g[0] == g0}, g, {x, 0, 1}]
g[.5] /. sol
ReImPlot[g@x /. sol // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

[image]

- We set `g[0]==g0` and `d` as parametric and using `ParametricNDSolve`. But it seems that `ParametricNDSolve` missing some lines.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f = 0.69; k = -0.001;
eqns2 = {g'[x]^2 == (f*g[x]^2) - k + d/g[x]};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eqns2, g[0] == g0}, g, {x, 0, 1}, {g0, d}]
g[1, 2]@.5 /. sol
ReImPlot[g[1, 2]@x /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify d. I set it arbitrarily to 1. Further I rationalize the constants and use NDSolve instead of DSolve. This makes it necessary to choose a starting value, I choose arbitrarily g[0] == 1. And I choose a time span from 0 to 1. With this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f = 69/100; k = -1/1000; d = 1;
eqns2 = {g'[x]^2 == (f*g[x]^2) - k + d/g[x], g[0] == 1};

sol2 = g[x] /. NDSolve[eqns2, g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

We can plot the result:

[image]

Comment: But there's no any plot line here?? could you put it please

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "plot line".

Answer (score 1):

Like this `d = 2; Plot[g[x]/.sol2, {x, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Did you try evaluating the code in the question and your answer?