# How to create direction field and phase line

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

Merry Christmas to all.

We have a problem we want to breed rainbowfish to sell to pet stores. We start with a nice big aquarium and 30 fish, half of them male, half of them female. We want to predict the number of fish after a number of days, to see how many you can sell.

So our initial condition for our rainbow fish is $(0)=30$.

Assume that one female rainbowfish lays eggs every 30 days and 42 of the eggs hatch into baby fish, half of them male, half female.

The birth rate is $b=0.7$

The aquarium owner expects to sell 20 rainbowfish per day.

The differential equation that defines the above problem is $$P'(t)=0.7P(t)-20$$.
I tried to solve this problem in Mathematica with the following code

```
eqn = p'[t] == 0.7 p[t] - 20
sol = DSolve[{eqn, p[0] == 30}, p[t], t]
```

Then I wanted to sketch the direction field and the phase line

```
VectorPlot[{1, p'[t] == 0.7 p[t] - 20}, {t, 0, 30}, {p, -50, 50}, 
 VectorStyle -> Red]
```

But this does not give me anything as a result.Any suggestion how to create direction field and the phase line please?

Comment: Do you mean StreamPlot[{1, .7 p - 20}, {t, 0, 30}, {p, 0, 50}]

Comment: see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276625/i-want-to-plot-the-solution-but  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ayv5.png)

Comment: @Moo Yes! Is there another way to create separately those two?

Comment: @Nasser I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not write:

```
{1, p'[t] == 0.7 p[t] - 20}
```

You must replace p by the first element of the solution and the second part does not make sense because it does not give a number. You must eliminate  "p'[t]==". Here is the corrected code:

```
VectorPlot[{1, 0.7 (p[t] /. sol[[1]]) - 20}, {t, 0, 30}, {p, -50, 50},
  VectorStyle -> Red]
```

[image]